# how I can make rabbitmq-server auto start at boot time?(centos 7)

Tags: linux, rabbitmq

I have tried too many times,but I failed.
I run order in shell ,it works,but I write it to supervisor or  /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ,both failed!

/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server start  (shell works)
supervisor or  /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ,both failed!

Comment: God,help me...... I have met a big problem.

Comment: when I add to supervisor,the log is:Session terminated, killing shell... –

Answer (score 3):

RabbitMQ on Centos7 uses the `systemd`.

You have to enable the service:

`sudo systemctl enable  rabbitmq-server`

Then try to reboot:

`Last login: Tue Sep  5 07:51:49 2017 from 10.0.2.2
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-09-05 07:57:05 UTC; 20s ago
 Main PID: 930 (beam.smp)
   Status: "Initialized"
   CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
           ├─ 930 /usr/lib64/erlang/erts-9.0.4/bin/beam.smp -W w -A 64 -P 1048576 -t 5000000 -stbt db -zdbbl 128000 -K true -- -root /usr/lib64/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/rabbitmq -- -pa /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.6.11.902/ebin -noshell -n...
           ├─1317 /usr/lib64/erlang/erts-9.0.4/bin/epmd -daemon
           ├─2354 erl_child_setup 1024
           ├─2437 inet_gethost 4
           └─2438 inet_gethost 4`

**EDIT**

It is the same for 3.3.5, see here:

`[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server
● rabbitmq-server.service - LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl enable  rabbitmq-server
rabbitmq-server.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig rabbitmq-server on
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo reboot
➜  centos7 vagrant ssh
Last login: Tue Sep  5 08:04:37 2017 from 10.0.2.2
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status  rabbitmq-server
● rabbitmq-server.service - LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-09-05 08:48:23 UTC; 9s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 972 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
           ├─1325 /bin/sh /etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
           ├─1335 /bin/bash -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server
           └─1339 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server`

RabbitMQ version:

`sudo rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@localhost ...
[{pid,1379},
 {running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.3.5"},`

**Note:**
You are using a very old RabbitMQ version, please consider to update it to the last one

Comment: What rabbitmq version are you using

Comment: 3.3.5 version,can you help me

Comment: RabbitMQ 3.3.5. Copyright (C) 2007-2014 GoPivotal, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@linux3.log
  ######  ##        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@linux3-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker... completed with 6 plugins.

Comment: 3.3.5 is a very old RabbitMQ version, I suggest to update it

Comment: Sorry @qsmy_qin but you are not giving enough information. `updated ,failed.` does not mean anything. Your issue is not related to RabbitMQ, I tried using your environment and it works correctly.


Next time you have to be more precise when you ask help.

Posting the error can help